# Why isn't my Angular Sequence Method working?

Tags: angular, typescript, sequence

Why isn't my Angular Sequence Method working (see entry-animation.ts code)?  The console is not throwing any errors and VS Code is compiling the typescript without any issues.

I am trying to get the `h1, h2, nav a` to animate before the `<p>` tags. I cannot delay the animation too long because I have navigation links that animate the `<p>` tags when the page is navigated to.  Any help is much appreciated!

**Stackblitz Example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4gthrs?file=null

**entry-animations.ts**

```
import {trigger, animate, style, transition, stagger, query, state, sequence} from '@angular/animations';

export const headingAnimation = trigger('headingAnimation', [
  transition('* => void', sequence([ 
    query('nav a', [
      style({ opacity: 0 }),
      animate('.25s .4s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
    query('p', [ 
      style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-10px)' }),
      stagger(400, [
          animate('0.35s .4s ease-in', style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ])) 
]);
```

**header.component.html**

```
<header id="content-container" @headingAnimation>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h2>Subtitle</h2>

<nav>
    <a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a>
    <a routerLink="about" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">About</a>
</nav>
```

**about.component.html**

```
<div @headingAnimation>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lorem libero, volutpat et laoreet ut, placerat sed urna.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lorem libero, volutpat et laoreet ut, placerat sed urna.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lorem libero, volutpat et laoreet ut, placerat sed urna.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a hunch as i no longer work with Angular professionally, but have you tried wrapping a `setTimeout` around your `transition`?

Comment: @r3wt - I did not as I thought there had to be a native "Angular/Typescript" way of accomplishing this.

Comment: @r3wt also, I need the animation to not have a delay on it when a user clicks a link to navigate to another page.  The setTimeout is unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. You need to change your transition from `* => void` to `:enter` or `void => *`.  What you have right now is only for leaving the view.
2. More importantly your sequence will never work because your elements are on different components.  In about the animation will fail because there are no `nav > a` elements and in header the animation will fail because there are no `p` elements.

The best you can do with number 2 is add `{optional: true }` as the third parameter to `query`, but the animations will begin at the same time.  Or, you could just create a second animation for the `p` elements and delay the ease-in longer to simulate the stagger effect.